# File input returns null in theme options array

Tags: theme-options, array, settings-api

Trying to work out a rather complex array situation with a theme options page.
While working with file upload I can't seem to get it to work.

Any idea what I might be missing?

Simplified example

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'rd_settings_menu' );
function rd_settings_menu() {
    add_options_page( 'Settings', 'Settings', 'manage_options', 'rd-settings', 'rd_settings_page' );
}

function rd_settings_page() {
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <h2><?php _e( 'Settings', 'site' ); ?></h2>
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="options.php" method="POST">
            <?php settings_fields( 'rd-settings-group' ); ?>
            <?php do_settings_sections( 'rd-settings' ); ?>
            <?php submit_button(); ?>
        </form>
    </div>
    <?php
}

register_setting( 'rd-settings-group', 'rd_fashion_list', 'rd_sanitize_section' );

add_settings_field(
    'rd_fashion_list',
    __( 'Fashion Blogs', 'site' ),
    'rd_fashion_list_callback_function',
    'rd-settings',
    'rd_blog_info_section'
);

function rd_fashion_list_callback_function() { ?>

    <input type="file" name="rd_fashion_list[0][img]">

<?php }

function rd_sanitize_section( $input ) {
    $input['0']['img'] = ( isset( $_FILES['rd_fashion_list']['0']['img'] ) ? section_image_upload( 'rd_fashion_list[0][img]', $input ) : 'nope' );
    return $input;
}
```

This will just return "nope".

A `var_dump($_FILES)` gives this:

```
Array(
    [rd_blog_img] => Array(
        [name] => [type] => [tmp_name] => [error] => 4[size] => 0
    ) [rd_logo_img] => Array(
        [name] => [type] => [tmp_name] => [error] => 4[size] => 0
    ) [rd_fashion_list] => Array(
        [name] => Array(
            [0] => Array(
                [img] => 1447272171.jpg
            )
        ) [type] => Array(
            [0] => Array(
                [img] => image / jpeg
            )
        ) [tmp_name] => Array(
            [0] => Array(
                [img] => / private / var /tmp / phplm0x7u
            )
        ) [error] => Array(
            [0] => Array(
                [img] => 0
            )
        ) [size] => Array(
            [0] => Array(
                [img] => 21033
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Can you please post your original code? The simplified version does not work at all, and as your original does, it would just be a waste of time to correct it ;)

Comment: @fischi I've progressed a bit and thus have created a new question with simplified code (although should be working this time) here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/135186/multiple-file-inputs-in-array-in-theme-options